# Can't get images into proper container. Images stacked, divs out of order?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, hover, mouseover

I'm a visual designer, so this may seem a silly question (and at one point, this wasn't broken!) but I'm stuck. I'm trying to get images to appear in a responsive row with a mouseover.

Can anyone help? I know the code is jacked; I've been struggling with the order of the divs. The mouseover is working, BUT the images are now stacking and aren't appearing in a row anymore. They're outside of the col-lg-4 container, but I've included that. What am I missing?

*image is FPO

/// HTML:

```
      <div class="col-lg-12">
          <div class="highlight">
              <h3>LOREM IMPSUM DOLAR</h3>
              <h5>The fox and the rabbit.</h5>
            </div>
       </div>


    <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <figure class="cap-left">
                    <div class="thumbnail">
                        <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/eb/T_Roosevelt.jpg/473px-T_Roosevelt.jpg" alt="">
                            <figcaptions><h4>Please let this work</h4></figcaptions>
                    </div>
                </figure>
            </div>
         </div>


      <div class="col-lg-4">
                <figure class="cap-left">
                    <div class="thumbnail">
                        <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/eb/T_Roosevelt.jpg/473px-T_Roosevelt.jpg" alt="">
                            <figcaptions><h4>Please let this work</h4></figcaptions>
                    </div>
                </figure>
            </div>
         </div>
```

/// JSFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/zvcNa/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to your `padding: 30px 40px;` for figcaptions{}.

figcaptions is 100% width and height, but add your padding to this size.

Remove this padding and add it to your figcaptions children :

```
figcaptions h4{
    padding:30px;    
}
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/zvcNa/1/)**

**EDIT #1:**
Replaced :

```
figure {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
}

.col-lg-4 {
    display:block;
    float:left;
  }
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/zvcNa/3/)**

Comment: Great, thanks so much! My question remains though, in wondering why the images are stacking on one another, as opposed to showing up in a row? I left the hover information in my original question because if I take that information out of my code, the images align properly, but if I leave it in, something's amiss. But, I need that mouseover, so I'm still stuck. :/

Comment: Sorry, i misunderstood half the question. I've updated my answer, you can find a fix. Don't hesitate to give more précisions if it is not what you were expecting.

Comment: No worries! AND, you are amazing! Thanks so much! I looked at this for so long; it took another pair of eyes. I'll learn this web development thing, yet. Again, thanks! :D